# Laravel register form does not return any error

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I am using the default classes of the Laravel registration. The problem:
When I submit my form, I know there are errors, because the users isn't added in the database. But when I use

```
{{dd($errors)}}
```

The result is

```
ViewErrorBag {#226 ▼
  #bags: []
}
```

My Validation rules are

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }
```

And the registration form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" class="form-signin">
        @csrf
        <img src="img/branding.svg">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">{{__('Registreer')}}</h2>
        <label for="email" class="sr-only">E-mailadres</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mailadres" required autofocus>
        <label for="name" class="sr-only">Gebruikersnaam</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" required>
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Wachtwoord</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required>
        <label for="password_confirmation" class="sr-only">Wachtwoord</label>
        <input type="password" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Wachtwoord (herhaal)" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">{{ __('Registreren') }}</button>
        {{dd($errors)}}
        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
        @endif
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
        @endif
    </form>
```

Everything looks fine, but I don't know why Laravel don't list the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Laravel did'nt have write access to the session directory (storage/framework/sessions/)
After I've changed it to a proper setting I was able to see the error messages

```
chmod 777 -Rv storage/
```

(R = recursively)
(v = verbose)